# Detect PictureBox's image change in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 windows, Register and User Profile. In Register, user can upload their profile picture and save to MySQL database as BLOB. After user login, he can update all personal information including his profile picture.

This is my code to update the profile picture:

```
void UpdateProfileClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs;
    BinaryReader br;

    if(usernameUser.Text=="" || passwordUser.Text=="" || namaLengkapUser.Text=="" || tglLahirUser.Text=="" || pekerjaanUser.Text=="" || alamatUser.Text=="" || noHpUser.Text=="" || foto.Image==null )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data belum lengkap. Isilah semua data anda.", "Register Gagal", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    koneksi.Open();

    string FileName = fototext.Text;
    byte[] ImageData;
    fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update user set nama=@nama, password=@password, tanggal_lahir=@tanggal_lahir, pekerjaan=@pekerjaan, alamat=@alamat, no_hp=@no_hp, image=@image where username=@username", koneksi);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"nama", namaLengkapUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"password", passwordUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"tanggal_lahir", tglLahirUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"pekerjaan", pekerjaanUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"alamat", alamatUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"no_hp", noHpUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"username", usernameUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"image", ImageData);

    try{
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data profil berhasil di-edit.", "Sukses", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        namauser.Text = namaLengkapUser.Text;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex){
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    koneksi.Close();    
}
```

The problem is if the user updates their personal information but doesn't update the profile picture, an error appears. So, the user needs to update the profile picture in order to prevent the error.

So, this is the code that matters.

```
string FileName = fototext.Text;
byte[] ImageData;
fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
br = new BinaryReader(fs);
ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
br.Close();
fs.Close();
```

I want that if `PictureBox`'s image change, execute the above code, else ignore the above code.

But how do I do it? Is it possible to use IF statement?

Thank you.

Comment: *"but doesn't update the profile picture"* - try to write this condition in *non-human* way, e.g. is text is empty or if button wasn't clicked.

Comment: if no new image has been loaded - dont try updating it?

Comment: @Sinatr it means the profile picture isn't changed by the user. The problem is everytime the user want to update his profile, he has to change his profile picture.

Comment: @BugFinder that's why I need an IF statement to execute the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just blindly creating your byte data regardless. if you check `FileName` or `fototext.Text` for emptyness you should be great. For example:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(FileName))
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

or if you know it should be a file, you could do

```
if (File.Exists(FileName))
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Empty or invalid entries will not be attempted then. Although you'd probably want an exception if they did type something but didn't give the right path. if you did that check it would silently fail.

This will also require you to dynamically add the "image" bit of your SQL depending on if a new file has been presented.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Could you tell me how to store image to database unblindly?

Comment: Look at string builder which can be used to build up the SQL you are creating dynamically, based on the same check you did earlier. if the check fails, dont add the bit of SQL for inserting the image, likewise dont add the bind variable if it's not been loaded. Or just insert the old image data (but that's the messy and horrible option)

Answer (score 1):

[PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox_events(v=vs.110).aspx)  has an event `BackgroundImageChanged`. You can try with this event.

Comment: I use Image instead of Background Image. But I think that's the same in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to return the checksum of the original image and compare it to the checksum of the current image.  If the checksum has changed then the image has changed.